# Possibility of linking a user/profile to a previously-created name linked to a model via a foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django application where registered users can add, through an input form, details of performances of their music ensemble. This application also has a a section for composers, where they add their own composition. I'm using a custom user model, with profiles linked to user accounts:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", unique=True, max_length=255)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
[...]

class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
[...]
```

This is my 'composition' model:

```
class Composition(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120) # max_length = required
    composer = models.ForeignKey(
      settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
      on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
[...]
```

And this is my 'performance' model. The performance information links to the piece performed (`performed`):

```
class Performance(models.Model):
performed = models.ManyToManyField(Composition, blank=True)
[...]
```

So far, so good. Now, I'd like the performers to be able to add pieces by composers who are not (yet) registered to the website. Let's say that the performer performed a piece by John Lennon and is adding information about that performance. So, the performer will need to be able to add both John Lennon, his composition, and link the two.

The most important bit is: if the ghost of John Lennon tomorrow wants to register to the website, the administrator of the website will need to be able to easily link the compositions already added by the performers to John Lennon's newly created account. Is that possible? I suppose the key to solving this issue is changing `composer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL...` with something else, i.e. using a intermediary model. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do this, you should choose one based on your taste:

- When you know that the actual user is registered, just delete the old, fake user referred in the composition and replace it with the actual user.
- Create a new model named something like `Artist` and change the composer relationship to refer to the `Artist` model. then, link the `Artist` model to the actual user with a nullable foreign key.

Comment: Your second option sounds interesting. Apologies for the basic question: how do I ' link the Artist model to the actual user with a nullable foreign key'? I guess I create a new model: class Artist(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=120) and then the composition model:     will have composer = models.ForeignKey(Artist).

Comment: @HBMCS Just add `null=True, blank=True` to the foreign-key, so if the `composer` relation is null, you know that the actual user haven't registered on the website yet. Set null like this: `composer = models.ForeignKey(
      settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
      on_delete=models.CASCADE,
      null=True,
      blank=True
    )`

Comment: why  settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL? Am I not linking the composer to the newly-created artist model? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes of course, but the relation between `Composition` and `Artist` is never null! every composition belongs to an artist. But the relation between the `Artist` model and the `User` model should be nullable; Because you can't say if every single artist is registered on the website. When the user actually registers on your website, you will assign that user to the respective artist.

Comment: Actually I meant `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True )` inside the artist model - It was my mistake

Comment: yes, that's the route I was investigating. It's all fine BUT: I need a name for the Artist, which ideally is sourced by the profile's name if the user is registered, and from the name the performer entered when added the performance's details if not. Too complicated?  Do I just add a 'name' field to the Artist's model, which will duplicate the name of the user is present? It sounds the only way.

Comment: you can also add a nullable `name` field to the `Artist` model. Whenever you want to read the name follow these flow: When the `user` foreign-key is null, you'll read the name from the artist model. But if there was actually a user attached to the artist, you should ignore the `name` column and directly read the name from the user relation itself.

Comment: Absolutely, I'm just implementing the code and testing it today, will leave feedback soon.